# Single Byte Multiplication in Python?

Tags: python, byte, multiplication

I have a requirement to decode a file using simple byte multiplication

For every byte in the file, the byte value is muliplied by 0x69. The result cannot be a word, it must be a single byte.

example:

```
0x24 * 0x69 = 0xc4
0x6c * 0x69 = 0x4c
etc.
```

Sorry for not posting code, but have no idea on an existing approach. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
(0x6c * 0x69) & 0xFF
```

?

And if you want the hex representation in a string, you can do:

```
hex(result)
```